# IntelliJ/PyCharm - where do I change what happens when I double click a file?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

I want PyCharm (IntelliJ) to display HTML-files in a browser, not open them in an editor, when I double click them in the project browser. Googling for a solution didn't return anything useful. Is this possible? How?

(This request also applies to PNG and some other filetypes but HTML is my main need at the moment)

Answer (score -1):

Both IDEA and PyCharm are editors, and they will default to *editing*; that is, they will open the HTML file and allow you to edit it *instead* of displaying any kind of web page.

If you want to see the rendered HTML, you can hover to the top right corner and select one of the browsers recognized by IntelliJ and installed on your system to open it in a browser then. Be aware that this may not render things correctly if you rely on a language-specific functionality (like JSP, Jinja2 templates or Less) to generate code on your behalf.

Comment: My HTML-files are logs, hence the request. I constantly right click them and then have to go into a submenu to open them in a browser.